# Unable to Set Up MySQL Dependency in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, homebrew, mysql-connector, swift-package-manager

I am trying to connect my Xcode project to a MySQL database using the Perfect MySQL package. I'm consistently getting "file not found errors" for each of these #include lines in my mysql.h file:

```
#include "mysql_version.h"
#include "mysql_com.h"
#include "mysql_time.h"
#include "my_list.h" /* for LISTs used in 'MYSQL' and 'MYSQL_STMT' */
#include "mysql/client_plugin.h"
```

When I look at the file which contains mysql.h in finder, all these files do exist in the same local directory. This is the directory where they all appear (after installing MySQL with HomeBrew):

/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.44_1/include

I had a previous compile time error which might tie into this one. I was getting something like "usr/local/include/mysql directory not found". I wasn't able to edit the file that included the path to the mysql file, so I fixed the error by creating a semilink from "usr/local/include/mysql" to the actual mysql file location (above). Now I'm starting to wonder if that created more problems than it solved.

[These](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3uNa.png) are my package dependencies. I am also getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv1jJ.png) warning which I have no idea how to decipher.

I am new to working with the Xcode package manager (as I'm sure it shows). That being said, I was very careful to follow all the steps in the [README](https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-MySQL) for Perfect MySQL package.

Here is what my package.swift file looks like if that helps:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Ecommerce App (COMP 230 Proj)",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "Ecommerce App (COMP 230 Proj)",
            targets: ["Ecommerce App (COMP 230 Proj)"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-MySQL.git", from: "3.0.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "Ecommerce App (COMP 230 Proj)",
            dependencies: ["PerfectMySQL"],
            cSettings: [
                .headerSearchPath("usr/local/include/mysql"),
            ]
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "Ecommerce App (COMP 230 Proj)Tests",
            dependencies: ["Ecommerce App (COMP 230 Proj)"]),
    ]
)
```